# Disable Comments Feed

Tags: comments, feed

I am working on a private site where the comments need to be hidden. I know how to remove the comments feed from the header, but can anyone give me some instructions on how to disable the comments feed altogether. Because all you need to do is add /feed/ to the single post and then you can see the comments feed.

I tried creating feed-atom-comments.php, and feed-rss2-comments.php, and that still did not work.

Comment: Related: Disable insertion of the sitewide comments feed URL in HTML header: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56695/disable-comment-rss-feeds-for-pages-in-wordpress

Comment: Related: Disable insertion of per-post comments feed URLs in HTML header: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190509/where-to-remove-link-from-comments-feed/309509#309509

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
function wpse45941_disable_feed( $comments ) {
    if( $comments ) {
        wp_die( 'No feed available' );
    }
}
add_action('do_feed', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
```

Note: I haven't tested that at all, I just wrote it right into the answer box.

Comment: I just tested this for a client of mine, and so far seems to be working perfectly. The specific problem was to turn off comments feed for individual posts. Thank you :-)

Comment: Note that this will disable ALL comments feeds, including the main one at `site.com/commentes/feed/` and not just the per-post ones like `site.com/postpermalink/feed/`. Maybe you want that, but it's important to note. (I'm hoping for a solution that keeps the global feed but not the per-post ones)

Answer (score 2):

### Disable only the individual-post comment feeds

An alternate version of mor7ifer's answer, this one **only** disables the per-post comment feeds, and not the site-wide comments feed (by checking for `is_single()` before doing `wp_die()`).

It also uses the [`410` error code which means `GONE`](https://moz.com/learn/seo/http-status-codes) and seems appropriate for this use-case (at least for me, where these URLs already existed and are indexed, and I want to unequivocally tell Google and friends to stop indexing).

```php
function wpse45941_disable_feed( $comments ) {
    if( $comments and is_single() ) {
        wp_die( 'Feeds for comments on single posts have been disabled.', 410 );
    }
}
add_action('do_feed', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
```

### Disable all comment feeds

Here's the same code with the `410` HTTP status, but it will also disable the sitewide comments feed (and shows an appropriate message):

```php
function wpse45941_disable_feed( $comments ) {
    if( $comments ) {
        wp_die( 'Feeds for comments have been disabled.', 410 );
    }
}
add_action('do_feed', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'wpse45941_disable_feed',1 );
```

#### Note: This doesn't fix the `<item>` for each post in the normal RSS feed

On further inspection, I've found the following error when validating the main (posts) RSS feed for my site:

[image: Screenshot of an error in the W3 feed validator: "Sorry - This feed does not validate. - line 111, column 19: wfw:commentRss must be a full and valid URL: (15 occurrences) [help]]

It seems WP is still inserting the comments RSS tag into the feed, but because that feed is disabled, it generates an error.

RSS still works, but I'm looking for a solution to get rid of it. [This Core Trac issue is relevant](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9134)

Comment: Added code to `functions.php` and it's not working - feeds for individual page comments are not removed