# Disable comment rss feeds for pages in wordpress

Tags: php, rss

I am currently working on the completion of a custom template and my last hurdle is to be able to remove the comments feed link being added to the head of the page.

For example: in firefox when you open any of the pages on my site there is an rss icon, when clicked I am shown 3 options to add to my reader but the last two are related to comments.

The culprits are located in the

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Example Title &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://example.com/comments/feed" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Example Title &raquo; Home Page Comments Feed" href="http://example.com/home-page/feed" />
```

I wish to have the main feed, which contains blog posts from the blog area of the site but do not want any comments, therefore comment feeds are useless to me!

I am wondering if there is a way I can remove these via the functions.php or some way through wordpress rather than coming up with another (messier) solution?

Thanks,
Tristan

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126174/disable-comments-feed-but-not-the-others

Comment: Related: **How to disable the comments feed entirely with wp_die()**: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45941/disable-comments-feed/361130#361130

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to `functions.php`

```php
add_filter('post_comments_feed_link', '__return_null');
```

Comment: This removed one of the links in the head, the following still remains: <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Example &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://example.com/comments/feed" />

Comment: In this case you have to edit wp-includes/feed-atom-comments.php and delete the line with the comments_link_feed(), as it uses   get_comments_link and there's no filter to disable it as it's with post_comments_feed_link.

Comment: This question answers how to remove the site-wide comments feed with simple filter code: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126174/disable-comments-feed-but-not-the-others

Comment: Note: it will remove tag from your page's code, but direct link will be still working so your comments feed stay exposed

Comment: For secure feed removal check https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162833/102310

Answer (score 1):

This is what most plugins and devs use:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3);
```

Add it in your theme's functions.php (before the last `?>` if you don't know what you are doing).

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me on Wordpress 3.3.2.
In a category page, for example I had:

```
application/rss+xml" title="title feed" href="http://www.example.com/feed/" />
application/rss+xml" title="Title Comments Feed" href="http://www.example.com/comments/feed/" />
application/rss+xml" title="Title Category Feed" href="http://www.example.com/cat/feed/" />
```

To remove the **first** and the **second line** (main feed and comments feed), I'v haded the following code to /wp-content/themes/my-theme-name/functions.php

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links', 2); 
add_action('wp_head', 'my_feed_links');
```

On main page none of those will be displayed.

Comment: WordPress 3.3.2 is outdated and should not be used anymore.

Comment: True! :) Also worked on **Wordpress 3.4.2**.

Comment: Note feed still exists you just don't link to it.