# Disable comments feed, but not the others

Tags: feed

I'd like to customize my WordPress blog in such a way that it is no more possible to access the comments feed.

Other feeds should still be available, and it should still be possible to add comments to any article.

I tried to find a plugin to do this, but what I found is a all or nothing feature, without the possibility to finely adjust which feeds are allowed and which are not.

Comment: Just want to add a reasoning for this: Having them enabled means that scrapers like Google/Bing/Yandex/etc. are constantly querying for both every article on my site (hundreds of thousands) AND their /feed/ URLs. This is a huge burden on the server and a huge waste of resources to serve these files which are almost ever relevant and unlikely to be used meaningfully but readers (who can subscribe by email if they want to).

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56695/disable-comment-rss-feeds-for-pages-in-wordpress

Comment: Related: **How to disable the comments feed entirely with wp_die()**: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45941/disable-comments-feed/361130#361130

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function remove_comment_feeds( $for_comments ){
    if( $for_comments ){
        remove_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'do_feed_rss2', 10, 1 );
        remove_action( 'do_feed_atom', 'do_feed_atom', 10, 1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'remove_comment_feeds', 9, 1 );
add_action( 'do_feed_atom', 'remove_comment_feeds', 9, 1 );
```

Comment: Am I missing something?  How/where does `$for_comments` get defined?

Comment: This is the original callback - do_action( $hook, $wp_query->is_comment_feed ), where it serve the variable $comments in the hooked function.

Comment: Yeah, I just read the snippet on the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/) page under `do_feed_$feed`:  *Action function argument: `true` (the feed is for comments) or `false` (it is for posts).*

Comment: thank you for this very fast answer. I'm not sure what to do with this code : where should I put it ?

Comment: active themes functions.php file, or in an active plugin file.

Comment: This isn't good. /feed still returns 200OK and the link to /feed still shows up on the post source.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned by @glueckpress, Since 4.4 you can use the `feed_links_show_comments_feed` filter.

Example (in your theme functions.php file) :

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'head_cleanup' );

function head_cleanup(){

    // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    // disable comments feed
    add_filter( 'feed_links_show_comments_feed', '__return_false' ); 

}
```

Comment: Note that there's also the core [`__return_false()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_false/) function available.

Comment: No effect whatsoever.

Comment: This worked for me to do the following: Hide the `site.com/comments` feed from being inserted into the header. It didn't hide the individual-post comments feeds that were in the header (`site.com/posturl/comments/`) in case that's what anyone was expecting (it's what I was looking for).

Comment: Related: **How to disable the comments feed entirely with wp_die()**: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45941/disable-comments-feed/361130#361130

Answer (score 1):

@Shazzad’s approach seems to not work when `current_theme_supports( 'automatic-feed-links' )`, because up to 4.3 WordPress seems to [be pretty ego about feed links](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.3/wp-includes/general-template.php#L2287-L2311). You would have to [`remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 )`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ce557062f4123d8513378cf415b4e8b612c33ccc/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L209) hard and add your own function printing only the link for post feeds.

However, from 4.4 this seems to get easier with a brand-new filter:  [`feed_links_show_posts_feed`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/504cd3bf15a754e9888fcba43f9e963c91fce527/wp-includes/general-template.php#L2311-L2320).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to remove the comments feed and posts comments feed.  As of Wordpress 5.4.2, this worked for me.

Add this into your "after_setup_theme" action.

```
add_theme_support('automatic-feed-links');
```

Add this right after that line:

```
add_filter( 'feed_links_show_comments_feed', '__return_false' );
```

After your "after_setup_theme action, add this function and filter ( I pulled this function from https://jeffvautin.com/2016/03/removing-comments-rss-feeds-from-wordpress/ blog.) It will removed the posts comments feed.

```
/**
 * Remove the posts comments rss feed 
 */
function disablePostCommentsFeedLink($for_comments) {
  return;
}
add_filter('post_comments_feed_link','disablePostCommentsFeedLink');
```

I also add this to remove those non-essential feeds

```
/**
 * remove non-essential rss feeds
 * 
 * This removes feeds like tags, authors, search, post type
 */
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
```

I believe this will just give me the main feed.  I'm not sure if this is the best way of going about this, but seems to do the trick.