# How to remove CPT comment feed from head?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, 404-error, rss, feed

In a custom post type I have set `has_archive` to `false`. In the head of a CPT page however I still find a link to a feed like this:

```
<link … title="Page Title | Comments Feed" href="domain/cpt/slug/feed/" />
```

The feed doesn't exist – the link generates a 404 error. I tried to remove the link with the filter `feed_links_show_comments_feed` which only had an effect on the regular posts' comment feed:

```
add_filter( 'feed_links_show_comments_feed', '__return_false' );
```

…the cpt comment feed was still there.

I also tried to rmove **all** feeds – which again worked on all feeds but the one I wanted to remove:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
```

If I however would set `has_archive` to `true` the link would actually lead to a valid rss feed of comments – which I basically wouldn't mind. But I can not have `has_archive` set to `true` since I need the base slug for some custom page and I don't want an archives page to appear on the slug's url.

I hope somebody can point me in the right direction? All pointers welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following command hides comments feed for posts (WP 4.4+ required!), but custom pages still have comments feed displayed, even if comments are disabled for such page:

```
add_filter( 'feed_links_show_comments_feed', '__return_false' );
```

To resolve this, I had to add this addidtional code too:

```
function remove_comments_rss( $for_comments ) {
    return;
}
add_filter('post_comments_feed_link','remove_comments_rss');
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to WPSE. Can you edit your answer to explain how it answers the question and what the code does? Code only answers are discouraged as they don't teach. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the comments feed for a custom post type by telling WordPress that comments are closed for a particular post type using the [`comments_open`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comments_open/) filter:

```
  function close_comments( $open, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'cpt' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
      $open = false;
    }
    return $open;
  }
  add_filter( 'comments_open', 'close_comments', 10, 2 );
```

Make sure you replace 'cpt' with your post type name.

Comment: Just to clarify, this seems to *actually close comments* on the post type, with the feed link not showing up effectively being a side-effect. That's a pretty major deviation from the actual goal here.